# Why are object's private members accessible to objects of the same type?

Tags: c++, private

I was surprised to discover that this compiles.

```
class A
{
    int i;
public:
    A() {}
    A(A &a) {i = a.i;}
};

int main(void)
{
    A a1;
    A a2(a1);
}
```

That is, the object `a2` has access to the private members of the object `a1`. Why is this the case i.e. why is this useful? How can this access be restricted, if needed?

Comment: This is *exactly* what `private` does

Comment: What a curious question. I hope it generates interesting responses.

Comment: Those modifiers restrict access on classes, not instances. That's simply how they work.

Comment: Bear in mind that, since you are the one creating the class, you are the one controlling how it is used. No one is making you access the other instance's members, so what use would this protection be?

Comment: For example, if access control were per-instance, implementing a copy constructor would require every single member variable to have a public getter.

Comment: Also, consider `class A { int i; public: void foo(A& a) { a.i = 0; } }; int main() { A b; b.foo(b); }`. If `b.foo(b);` should succeed (`b` is accessing its own private member) then access control must be performed at runtime.